# Issue with bottom padding/margin with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm working on quickly building a website theme (Wordpress) with the aid of Twitter bootstrap, and I'm running into a problem.

I've got a header thrown together, and I've got this weird gap going on inside the "pull-right" section, not sure why:

[image]

I'm not sure what the deal is, I want them sitting on the line right at the same height of the text on the left.

Anyway, I've got the following relevant sections of code:

(HTML for header section):

```
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="row header-container">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <h3>CharlesBaker.net</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

(CSS for the same section):

```
.header-container {
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #880000;
}

.header-container h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', serif;
}

.header-container ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header-container ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header-container a {
    padding: 3px;
    color: black;
}

.header-container a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #880000;
    color: white;
}
```

Not sure what the issue is, unless it's related to the fact that I'm using a  tag instead of just styling a `<span>` or something, but since I removed the padding/margin using CSS, I wouldn't think that would be the problem.

Any help would be great.   The idea is that when I hover over the links on the right, that they're enclosed in a scarlet colored box that "extends" from the 5px bottom border.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do it like this. [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/9n39M/) Or sitting on a line like [**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/9n39M/1/). Pretty sure there not the best ways to do it but still. They work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ghv8k/2/)?

You need to set your `.header-container` as `display: inline-block` to align all elements inside. Therefore, you need to float your pull `div` elements (float and left).
Just one last change, set the width size of your header: I set 100%, but you can set whatever you like :)

**CSS**:

```
.header-container {
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #880000;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.pull-left {
    float: left;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Put just the relevant CSS you change and explain it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a particular line-height property for `h3` tag with bootstrap.

```
h1, h2, h3 {
    line-height: 40px;//line 760
}
```

So you will have to add style to negotiate this additional height.

Also another set for your ul as :

```
ul, ol {
    margin: 0 0 10px 25px; //line 812
}
```

Solution :

1. Over-ride the ul margin as follows :

   ```
   .pull-right ul{
       margin: 0;
   }
   ```
2. Over-ride the line-height for the h3 as follows :

   ```
   .pull-left h3{
       line-height:20px;
   }
   ```

First one is pretty straight forward and gives you correct alignment straighaway. Second solution will need you to work some more with tweaking the negative-margins for `.pull-right`.

Debugging URL : http://jsbin.com/oToRixUp/1/edit?html,css,output

Hope this helps.